# Do I need to enable sandbox network capabilities for macOS In App Purchases (IAP)?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, appstore-sandbox, entitlements

Do I actually need to configure the network capabilities of my sandbox for IAP? Clearly, I want to talk to the App Store, so I need the "Outgoing Connections (Client)". But on the other side, it feels wrong to enable network capabilities only for this use case. What is the correct setting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My testing tells me that one does need to turn outgoing connections on.